# Seeing a deleted question in the newest questions list

Tags: bug, status-norepro, deleted-questions, newest-questions

I just saw the troll question on the deleted post "You'll hear from FBI".

When I checked in it had a score of -3, I downvoted, flagged and reloaded the page. The question was deleted... but then I checked my newest questions and found this:

[image: newest questions tagged c#]

Comment: "The answer is "caching". What is the question?" ["What is always the answer?"](http://i.imgur.com/TCOCzvr.jpg).

Comment: @Bart so this is unwanted result of caching... then this question here does not make much sense huh? well that would be clear then;)

Comment: I'm assuming it to be. Seems like a logical explanation.

Comment: ***WESSIDE!!!***

Comment: Now I want to read the rest of that question...

Comment: @Dukeling just get 10k rep on main and you can look all you want

Comment: I do, but I don't have a link to the question.

Comment: Its a shame really, im sure gangsters and trash mobs could really use a good copy of linux